# Excel Pivot Table: Grand Total Average

Tags: excel, pivot, average

I have traffic volumes counted for many days. What I want is to select dates, and make Pivot Table show me the totale volume per day, but the **average grand total** of the sum (Grand Total divided by the number of dates selected). If possible I would also like to show the number of dates selected. I have not found a solution to combine **sum of** and **average** in the same Pivot Table. Any tips?

What I am trying to achieve (but included in the Pivot Table):
[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kSDs.png)

I do not want to add any data to the input-sheet

**edit1:** there are 24 counting hours per day, so the sum of Volume per day is the sum of 24 cells per day.

**edit2:** adding Count of Dato results in "24" per day, and a Grand Total of 480 (if 20 days * 24). I want this to be 20, like number of selected dates. See picture: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgRga.png)

Comment: Is the volume per date from a single source cell or are they the sum of multiple volume cells in the source table?

Comment: For the date count, just add count of date in the value field also

Comment: @Daghan: Volume per dae are the sum of multiple cells (24 counting hours per day)

Comment: @Daghan: see edits in my main question